# Unable to download spring boot jars from maven repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

[image]

I am unable to download the jars for springboot.
I have settings.xml pointing to some other repository.
Could someone please suggest the repository to be added to download spring jars or share the settings.xml file so that this error gets fixed.

Comment: You have wiped out the interesting information... (better would have been to past the text into the post instead of a picture) which URL do you use? Apart from that looks like a network error..but I can't be sure based on the missing onformation...

Comment: Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for toDoList:toDoList:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-start-parent:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/): central.maven.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: Are you using http or using https? Which Java version do you use?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_281" and I tried both http and https..

Comment: Also tried this 
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for toDoList:toDoList:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-start-parent:pom:2.4.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM 


{  <repository>
           <id>central</id>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com/</url>
            </releases>
        </repository> }

Comment: Is your network in a proxy environment?

Comment: No Susil95. Not a proxy network